# MySQL truncate error

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying remove all data and reset the AUTOMATIC_INCREMENT to the value of 0, so that I have a clean database to work with. Found a truncate function that should allow me to to do the above however it throws back this error.... **Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint**

```
(`film`.`reviewed`, CONSTRAINT `reviewed_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `film`.`films` (`movie_id`))
```

Do this mean I have to remove the FOREIGN KEY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you cannot TRUNCATE the table that have Foreign key constraint to it

As per the **[docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html)**:-

> **TRUNCATE TABLE** fails for an InnoDB table if there are any FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints from other tables that reference the table. Foreign key
>   constraints between columns of the same table are permitted.

Although you have an alternative to do like this:-

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE table1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I don't recommend this approach since you might be leaving some dangling references behind. You are better off if you respect your FK constraints and truncate the tables in the right order. See my answer to this question.

Comment: @DMac:- Thats correct but I have just provided an alternative. I do have mentioned that "**you cannot TRUNCATE the table that have Foreign key constraint to it**"

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate tables with foreign key constraints; I do it all the time. But you have to satisfy the constraints in the right order.

If you have two tables, TABLEB has a FK constraint referencing TABLEA, then you have to TRUNCATE TABLEB first, and then TABLEA.

To be clear, if TABLEB includes the constraint

```
CONSTRAINT `xid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`xid_fk`) REFERENCES `TABLEA` (`id`)
```

Then you CAN'T truncate TABLEA first, because that would create dangling references in TABLEB. However, if you truncate TABLEB first, you will then be able to truncate TABLEA with no errors.